# Can't write regular expression

Tags: c++, regex, qt

I have this string

```
<meta itemprop="name" content="some text" />
```

I have no ideas how to write regular expression to get only `some text` part of above string.

Comment: No need to downvote a specific question, even if it's lacking more than a bit... He's clearly out of his depth and has no idea how to implement it. There's no hard in providing an answer with an explanation.

Comment: I strongly suggest: http://www.regexbuddy.com/ develop, test and learn RegEx.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your regex **pattern**. Here you go:

```
(?<=content=").*?(?=")
```

**Part 1**: `(?<=content=")`
Explanation: This does a "Positive Lookbehind" to verify a literal match to **content="** before your desired text without including it inside of the actual match

**Part 2**: `.*?`
Explanation: This will look for anything between Part 1 and Part 3 and assign that as your match as few times (lazy) as possible

**Part 3**: `(?=")`
Explanation: This makes sure that there is a quotation mark (**"**) after your matched text using a "Positive Lookahead"

Now, regarding how one would implement this into C++, I leave that up to you. I'm only answering for the regex pattern for what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

i can recommend you looking at http://www.regular-expressions.info/, looking at [Learning Regular Expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions)  or reading the book i've read ... http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596528126.do

and if you cant handle them; use `QString::contains` and `QString::split` to get to your result

Comment: Any coder can "handle" regular expressions, but they have a steep learning curve for most people, especially those who have a hard time wielding syntax that isn't human-reading friendly. That being said, I do agree that one should at least look up what the heck they're trying to do before just posting a question on SO begging for help...